$E(XY) \ge0 \not\Rightarrow E(X \log Y) \ge0$: Covariance of $X$ and $\log Y$ can be negative even if correlation of $X$ and $Y$ is very close to $1$
When does the following implication hold:
$$\text{cov}(X,Y)=\mathbb E(XY) \ge0 \Rightarrow \text{cov}(X \log Y)=\mathbb E(X \log Y) \ge0 \tag{1}$$
where $\mathbb E(X)=0$, and $Y$ is a non-negative random variable with $\mathbb E(Y)=1? $
This is equivalent to
$$\text{cov}(Z,Y) \ge0 \Rightarrow  \text{cov}(Z,\log Y)\ge0 \tag{2}$$
where both $Z$ and $Y$ are non-negative with $\mathbb E(Z)=\mathbb E(Y)=1.$
I came across with this in my answer, where a condition of form (2) appeared as an equivalent condition for the KL divergence to satisfy the triangle inequality (see O1). I observed that in different cases where $\mathbb E(XY) \ge0$ holds, $\mathbb E(X \log Y) \ge0$ also holds (see O2, O3, and O4, and my final disscussion on their connection with O1).

Positive result:
When the correlation of $X$ and $Y$ is $1$, the above holds. In this case, we have $X=a Y-a$ for some $a\ge 0$, and thus $$\mathbb E(X \log Y)=a \mathbb E(Y\log Y)+a\mathbb E(-\log Y) \ge  a(1\log 1-\log 1)=0$$ by Jensen's inequality.

Negative result:
As nicely shown in @RobertIsrae's answer, even if $\text{corr}(X,Y)$ is arbitrarily close to $1$ ($X$ and $Y$ are highly positively correlated), $\text{cov} \left( X, \log Y\right ) \ge 0$ may not hold ($X$ and $\log Y$ can be negatively correlated).

I don't know general conditions for it, but I can generate counterexamples easily.  Start with some $X$ with $\mathbb E[X] = 0$ and $\mathbb P(X=0) < 1$, and any $Y$ with $\mathbb E[Y] = 1$ and $\mathbb E[XY] \ge 0$.
For convenience suppose there is $x_0$ with $\mathbb P(X=x_0) >0$, and let $W = I_{X=x_0}$ be the indicator random variable of $X = x_0$.
Take $0 < p < 1$ and $0 < a < 1$.  Let $b = \mathbb E[Y | X = x_0] = \mathbb E[Y | W = 1]$.
Let $B$ be a Bernoulli($p$) random variable independent of $X$ and $Y$,  $V$ a random variable independent of
$X$, $Y$ and $B$ with $\mathbb P(V = a) = 1/2$, $\mathbb P(V = 2b-a) = 1/2$, and $Y' = Y + W B (V - Y)$. Note that $\mathbb E[V] = b$.
Thus $\mathbb E[Y'] = 1$, $\mathbb E[XY'] = E[XY]\ge 0$, and
$$ \mathbb E[X \log(Y')] = \mathbb P(X \ne x_0) \mathbb E[X \log(Y) \mid X \ne x_0) + (1-p) \mathbb P(X = x_0) \mathbb E[X \log(Y) \mid X = x_0) + p \mathbb P(X = x_0) \mathbb E[\log(V)]$$
with $\mathbb E[\log(V)] \to -\infty$ as $a \to 0+$, and thus
$\mathbb E[X \log Y'] < 0$ for sufficiently small $a$.
EDIT: For examples with $\text{Corr}(X,Y)$ arbitrarily close to $1$, consider joint distributions of the following form:
$$ \eqalign{ \mathbb P(X=-1, Y = 1/2) &= 
             \mathbb P(X = 1, Y = 3/2) = 1/2 - \epsilon/2 \cr
             \mathbb P(X = 1, Y = \delta) &= \mathbb P(X = -1, Y = 2-\delta) = \epsilon/2\cr} $$
where $\epsilon > 0$ and $\delta > 0$ are small.
Then $\mathbb E[X] = 0$ , $\mathbb E[Y] = 1$,
$\mathbb E[XY] = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{3}{2} \epsilon + \epsilon \delta > 0$, and $\text{Corr}(X,Y) \to 1$ as $\epsilon, \delta \to 0$.  But because $\epsilon \log(\delta)$ can be an arbitrarily large negative number, $\mathbb E[X \log(Y)]$ can be negative.

Thanks for your answer that provides a constructive procedure for producing counterexamples. Using this procedure, is it possible to create an example where the correlation coefficient of $X$ and $Y$ is arbitrarily close to 1?

Thanks for the edit and interesting counterexample! Though the implication holds for $\text{Corr}(X,Y) = 1$, it does not necessarily hold even as $\text{Corr}(X,Y) \to 1$.

It does not seem to be always true.
Experimenting, if the following three values of $(X,Y)$ each have probability $\frac13$
   X       Y
  -3      0.7
   1      1.9
   2      0.4
 

then $\mathbb E[X]=0, \mathbb E[Y]=1, \mathbb E[XY]=0.2>0, \mathbb E[X\log Y]\approx -0.04 <0$.

Thanks for the example! Hope some conditions can be established.
